# ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive p-dropDown (prime ng element !)

Tags: angular, forms, dropdown, primeng

error message :
ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.  Example:

```
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <input formControlName="firstName">
</div>

In your class:

this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
   firstName: new FormControl()
});

  Or, if you'd like to avoid registering this form control, indicate that it's standalone in ngModelOptions:

  Example:

  
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
   <input formControlName="firstName">
   <input [(ngModel)]="showMoreControls" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
</div>
```

---

My Html Code :
`

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cities"  placeholder="Select a City *"  optionLabel="name" [showClear]="true"formControlName="city" #city id="city" name="city" ></p-dropdown>
```

`

i tried to use [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" and it doesn't work

Comment: Hi, can you reproduce this issue on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com)? Thanks.